# Grid - How to create custom grid with auto height?

Tags: css, grid

I want to have a layout something like this:

[image]

But, right now I have a layout with a grid-like this:

[image]

My question is, how to make (not only red but here is only one as an example) boxes to have a different height, no matters on `grid-template-rows` and etc...

My grid wrapper :

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Comment: I think you cannot achieve it with CSS alone, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Nevermind, here is [an example](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb) you can follow.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul, hi, thank you for your answer.  Please tell me how you would do it?